# Operator space mismatch

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, math-operators

Operator space differ for first number and subsequent numbers in inline math, how to fix it throughout in inline math? e.g., $-3   -3$

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
analyse the effects of business transactions on the accounting equation and on financial statements.

$-3   -3$

$-6   -6$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: those are not the same thing the first is a sign the other is an additional operator (minus), thus the spacings are different as they mean different things

Comment: Ok, how to fix it throughout and controlling template itself. $-3\quad\textrm{and}\quad   -3$

Comment: It should not be fixed that is the proper way to typeset this equation. Perhaps you should start by explaining what exactly it is you are trying to do and why you need to change the default.

Comment: use `{-}` to get a - that is not the infix operator compare `$3-3$` and `$3{-}3$`

Comment: but for your example I would use `$-3$ and $-3$`  as the `and` and spaces are part of the surrounding sentence, not part of the mathematics.

Comment: Maybe you want to use an `array` like this: `$\begin{array}{rr}-3 & -3\\-6 & -6\end{array}$`?

Comment: Just add `{}` before the first minus: `${}-3   -3$

${}-6   -6$`.